# Hyperbola question.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, coordinate-systems

Is it possible to solve the question in least amount of steps? My attempt: I first formed the equation of the normal and then I found out the points where it cuts the conjugate and transverse axis. After finding these points I used distance formula to find the distance required and convert it in the form that the question asked. But its a long method and took lot of steps[image]
I asked the same question last time but got no response..

Comment: You might have better luck getting responses if you’d take the time to type in crucial parts of your question instead of pasting an image of it.

Comment: That’s not the point. If you’re not going to take the time to make your question accessible to everyone that uses this site (images are not searchable and inaccessible to those using screen readers), why should anyone take their own time to help you?